# Apply function fails when function outputs aren't consistent ("TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()")

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a pandas series such as: `area_sqm = pd.Series(['200', '300 sqft' '300-400'])`

I want to parse these strings and return a numeric series. I wrote a couple of functions for this.

The first converts string to number if possible, otherwise, returns a NA value.

```
def as_numeric(value):
    try:
        return float(value)
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        return np.nan
```

The second parses the different types of strings:

```
def area_string_to_number(area_string):
    area_string=pd.Series(area_string)

    # Convert sqft to sqm
    if area_string.str.contains('sqft').sum():
        area_number = area_string\
                        .str.replace('sqft', '')\
                        .apply(as_numeric)
        area_number /= 10.7639
    # Take mean of range
    elif area_string.str.contains('-').sum():
        area_number = pd.Series(area_string.str.split('-'))\
                        .explode()\
                        .apply(as_numeric)\
                        .mean()
    else:
        area_number = area_string.apply(as_numeric)
    
    return area_number
```

Here are the outputs of a few different inputs to this function:

```
area_string_to_number('200') # returns pd.Series([200])
area_string_to_number('300 sqft') # returns pd.Series([27.870939])
area_string_to_number('300-400') # returns pd.Series([350])
pd.Series(['300', '400', '300sqft']).apply(area_string_to_number) # return pd.Series([300, 400, 27.870939])
pd.Series(['300', '300-400']).apply(area_string_to_number) # TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len()
```

In the first four cases, the results are as expected, but in the last case, I get the TypeError. Upon doing some analysis, the error seems to happen because the `elif` statement returns a number and not a pandas series. When I change the `return` statement of the second function to `return pd.Series(area_number)`, the error goes away and I get the expected outputs for all the inputs.

I just wanted to know why this is the case. I've just recently started using Pandas in Python (I've been an R user for a few years). I just wanted to get a basic understanding of why the apply function behaves this way.

Answer (score 3):

This code below made area_string is always treated as a Pandas Series within the function. When your function returns area_string as number for the first value '300', but then returns Series for '300-400', it causes type mismatch.

```
def area_string_to_number(area_string):
    area_string=pd.Series(area_string)

    # Convert sqft to sqm
    if area_string.str.contains('sqft').sum():
        area_number = pd.Series(area_string\
                        .str.replace('sqft', '')\
                        .apply(as_numeric))
        area_number /= 10.7639
    # Take mean of range
    elif area_string.str.contains('-').sum():
        area_number = pd.Series(area_string.str.split('-')\
                        .explode()\
                        .apply(as_numeric)\
                        .mean())
    else:
        area_number = pd.Series(area_string.apply(as_numeric))
    
    return area_number
```